# Eevee glass rendering grey

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, glass, reflection

So I'm using a Principled BSDF shader with transmission to 1 in Eevee. I've enabled screen space refraction in the shader and enabled screen space reflections and refractions in the render tab. I've covered so many solutions on stackexchange yet I'm still getting this gray in the glass.

I thought it was reflecting the background. I have changed the background to white (also tried blue) but it make no difference. I've played with the refraction depth and IOR, but nothing helps.

What is going on here?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: could you please share your file, or a part of it? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Cheers, just uploaded it.

Comment: it looks like glass is still not optimum un Eevee, as Christopher says you probably need to find a way around with Glossy, Transparent, Refraction nodes etc...

Answer (score 1):

I find this setup best to mimic proper glass in eevee. Pay attention to the Blend Modes I have highlighted (I didn't use a transparent shadow but you can if you want). You can leave the IOR at default, but I find 1.05 gives a better look for a lot of things.

[image: GlassEEVEE]

Comment: Thanks for your setup mate. I still get the grey in the non-geometry areas though. Although it does look quite nice regardless. Will try it again if I get this issue sorted.

Comment: Yeah, I see that not. You can remove some of it by removing the refraction component, but that leaves the glass "frostier" than it should look.

Comment: For some reason, your world background was interfering, until I noticed the "use nodes" checkbox was unchecked and then I checked it. That let the world light come through, which was way too bright. I just disconnected the background altogether, and things cleared right up Try for yourself - you may want to tweak settings afterwards to get the correct world lighting back

Comment: I've disconnected the nodes and still getting this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJUmE.png
I also reset the background all together. Did you get it working correctly?

Comment: You mean the sphere? I'm not sure what's going on there. As far as I can tell, there's something in your world setting causing this, but I can't put mu finger on it.

Comment: Yeah there must be. I just created a new scene and all works fine. I'll just have to build up things from the new scene. If I come across what causes it along the way I'll post it. Cheers for your help anyway.

Comment: Well, I set the refraction depth all the way down to 0.000001. that seemed to remove the grey but comes at a cost on not rendering the glass how it really should.