# Glass in eevee remains grey

Tags: eevee-render-engine, transparency, glass

I'm making a glass flask and I've stolen multiple different node setups from different tutorials online, yet all my glassware either remains partially opaque, or it looks like the transparent glass surface is a solid block of glass.

The node setup for the shader I use comes from this question:
[Eevee glass rendering grey](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/190893/eevee-glass-rendering-grey)

I looked at different SE posts with similar problems, but my solutions continues to elude me.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Enable the *Refraction* option in the *Render panel > Screen Space Reflections*:

[image]

Here is a basic node setup to get a glass texture, just plug a *Shader > Glass* node into the *Material Output*. For glass material the *IOR* must be around 1.5, and set the *Roughness* to a low value if you want reflectivity:

[image]

Keep the *Blend Mode* set to *Alpha Blend*:

[image]

Comment: that looks better, thanks. but now it looks like frosted and not a whole lot like actual glass. I think I fixed it? The Fresnel node was set to an IOR of 0.8, which is way lower than what actual glass is (and is in face lower than the IOR of air). I put it at 1.05 and it looks way better now.

Comment: it's due to your node setup, why don't you begin with a simple Glass shader?

Comment: I am very new to this so I can only rely on node setups I find somewhere. I don't know what all these different nodes actually do.

Comment: I've edited my answer, you can just plug a Glass node into the Output, keep the other parameters of your material